# Showing a selection list on a popup using UIActionSheet

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiactionsheet

I'm developing an iOS 5.0+ app with latest SDK.

I want to show a popup with some options to choose. But I don't know how to do it.

I have this code to show an `UIActionSheet` with a seven buttons:

```
- (void)setUserActivity
{
    activityActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                     delegate:nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@""
                                       destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [activityActionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];


    for (int index = 0; index < 7; index++)
    {
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [button addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(activitySelected:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, index*40 + 10, 160.0, 40.0);
        button.frame = frame;
        button.tag = index;
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %d", index] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [activityActionSheet addSubview:button];
    }

    CGRect toolbarFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, activityActionSheet.bounds.size.width, 44);
    UIToolbar* controlToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:toolbarFrame];

    [controlToolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
    [controlToolbar sizeToFit];

    UIBarButtonItem* spacer =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                  target:nil
                                                  action:nil];

    UIBarButtonItem* setButton =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Set", nil)
                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                    target:self
                                    action:@selector(dismissActivityActionSheet)];

    UIBarButtonItem* cancelButton =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", nil)
                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                    target:self
                                    action:@selector(cancelActivityActionSheet)];
    [controlToolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer, cancelButton, setButton, nil]
                    animated:NO];
    [activityActionSheet addSubview:controlToolbar];

    [activityActionSheet showInView:self.view];
    [activityActionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];
}
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

**How can I add a scroll to allow user click on button 6?** Or, **is there a better approach to do it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add an UIScrollView between your buttons and the ActivityActionSheet...

```c
...
UIScrollView *myButtonScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,160,441)];

for (int index = 0; index < 7; index++)
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(activitySelected:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, index*40 + 10, 160.0, 40.0);
    button.frame = frame;
    button.tag = index;
    [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %d", index] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    //[activityActionSheet addSubview:button];
    [myButtonScroll addSubView:button];
}

[myButtonScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(160, 7*40 + 20)];
[activityActionSheet addSubView:myButtonScroll];
...
```

Assuming there are only 7 buttons on your view...

Answer (score 3):

Is there any reason why you're adding buttons as a subview of the `UIActionSheet`?

The preferred method is to provide additional button titles in via the `otherButtonTitle` method parameter:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                    destructiveButtonTitle:@"Okay"
                                         otherButtonTitles:@"One", @"Two", @"Three", @"Four", @"Five", @"Six", nil];
```

Then if you conform to the delegate, you can use the method `actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` and determine which of the buttons was selected.

Comment: I'd also question a UI that needs to have a scrolling list of options like this. If you really need it, just pop to a new tableview controller with the options - it's a bit cleaner and more "iOS like"

Answer (score 0):

I would use a UIActionSheet only if you plan to insert the buttons through this method:

```
activityActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                 delegate:nil
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@""
                                   destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

You can easily insert the buttons as a list of strings i.e. `@"Button1",@"Button2",nil` (with a nil delimiter at the end) and pass it in the `otherButtonTitles` parameter.

If you want to use customised views (adding buttons to the view), I would rather use another control (create my own `UIView` subclass that acts similarly to `UIActionSheet`).